# Google Forms Apps Script Error (Exception: Could not add image, please wait a minute and try again)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-form-quiz

I am getting periodic errors with a Google Forms apps script error.  The code looks like this:

```js
var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(question_url);

form.addImageItem()
  .setImage(img)
  .setTitle("Question " + position)
```

And exceptions are thrown *periodically* with the message `Exception: Could not add image, please wait a minute and try again.` . I [had a look at the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item#setImage(BlobSource)), but, I can't see any limits there on what the size of the image can be. The image is 42KB in size and dimensions `781 * 572px`.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is meaning of `I am getting periodic errors with a Google Forms apps script error.`? 2. Can I ask you about the mimeType of the image data retrieved from `question_url`? 3. For example, when you use the image data of `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/Img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a` from [https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) is used, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Periodic errors: This happens from time to time, not for every requested image. `curl`ing the image returns `Content-Type: image/png` in the headers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand 2 answers in my 3 questions. About `Periodic errors: This happens from time to time, not for every requested image.`, when the error occurs, was the image correctly retrieved? For example, when an image file on Google Drive is used, what result will you obtain? About `curling the image returns Content-Type: image/png in the headers`, I think that this can be used with your script.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error unfortunately, all I can see is the errors that are being reported to me via the StackDriver logs. I do not actually know if the image was retrieved correctly. My assumption is that it _was_ because otherwise the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` call would have failed (rather than the addImage call). All of these fetches are for external images (serviced by cloudfront), nothing is fetched from Drive.

Comment: Use `try...catch` with `sleep` and/or `console.log(imageurl)` to catch the actual url that is failing?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, also I couldn't replicate your situation in my environment. I apologize for this.